# Laravel request - retrieve data

Tags: php, laravel

I need some help looping through my data that i submit via form:

```
{
  "_token": "MYJZs0EIuYMKvD7Y56R8DluxGu9vKJuNkMxXy2Ll",
  "name": "Routine 1",
  "sections": {
    "section-1": {
      "section-name": "Section 1",
      "exercises": {
        "1": {
          "name": "Exercise 1"
        },
        "2": {
          "name": "Exercise 2"
        }
      }
    },
    "section-2": {
      "section-name": "Section 2",
      "exercises": {
        "3": {
          "name": "Exercise 21"
        },
        "4": {
          "name": "Exercise 22"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": "Submit"
}
```

How can i properly loop through and access individual values?
I want it to print out:

```
<h2>Section 1</h2><br/>
<p>Exercise 1</p><br/>
<p>Exercise 2</p><br/>
<h2>Section 2</h2><br/>
<p>Exercise 21</p><br/>
<p>Exercise 22</p><br/>
```

I got stuck here:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request;

    $html = "";
    foreach($data as $element){
        $html .= "<h2>" . $element->name .'</h2>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

i know its, the store method, but before i save its data, i want to return myself plain html to see if everything is fine, so ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know its, the store method, but before I save its data, I want to return myself plain html to see if everything is fine, so ignore that.

If you want to do this.. why hit the server? You could show a modal to the user with the data of the request and just then after confirmation continue with the request to the server..

PS: I'm assuming that you are using Blade.

Anyway, ignoring that, you could return the data to the same view and loop the data there:

```
public function confirmData(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all(); // Getting your values (I'll suggest you to use only() instead)

    return view('some_view')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach($data as $key => $value)
  <span>{{ $value }}</span>
@endforeach
```

---

#### Update

To achieve what you want try this (I'm basing this on the json you posted):

```
public function confirmData(Request $request)
{
    $sections = $request->get('sections');

    $html = '';

    foreach($sections as $section)
    {
        $html .= "<h2> { $section['section-name'] } </h2>";

        foreach($section['exercises'] as $exercise)
        {
            $html .= "<p> { $exercise['name'] } </p>";
        }
    }

    // ...

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Its not for user, its just meant for me as im learning laravel atm. so i would like to do it in controller, so i can access specific values in case i need. I know that way its the "correct" way, but i wont use this later on

Comment: @mheonyae ok so you are learning. It'd be better if you describe what you want to achieve in order to guide you to the common way to do this in Laravel. Feel free to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60047931/edit) your post.

Comment: Well i want to achieve what i described, loop through the request data and access each value in a row so i would be able to build a " list" as mentioned above. Like how can i specify to loop through all "sections" and get the name of each and then exercises? I know i would have to nest multiple foreach depending on depth.

Comment: @mheonyae I've updated my answer, I hope that can guide you.